# Find the index of the start of a pattern in Matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, audio, pattern-matching

I'm new to Matlab and am trying to perform some basic functions.  I have a small sound file that I played over my PC's speaker and another sound file that contains recorded audio that encompasses the time that I played the first audio file.  After loading each file into Matlab as arrays I used xcorr on the two and stored the value as c.  What I would like to do is get the index in the c array that corresponds to the rough time that the small sound file was played.  Here is my code.

```
[tone,fs] = audioread('Tone1.wav');
[recording,fs] = audioread('recording1.wav');
c = xcorr(tone, recording);
```

[image]

The above is a plot of c.  I feel that it should be very straight forward to find the index in the array c that this pattern starts but I don't know the syntax.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position is determined by the maximum cross-correlation. However, it may be tricky to do it with `xcorr` because, according to its [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html), the shortest signal (`tone`) will be zero-padded, and so its length will be altered.

I suggest you use `conv` (convolution) instead of `xcorr`. The result of convolution is the same if you time-invert `tone`, and using `conv` has the advantage that it admits the `valid` option (see its [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)), which avoids zero-padding and thus allows you to directly read the time-position of the maximum.

Example:

```
>> tone = sin(2*pi*linspace(1,8,1000));
>> recording = [zeros(1,1e4) tone zeros(1,5e4) ];

>> c = conv(recording, tone(end:-1:1), 'valid');
>> [~, pos] = max(c)

pos =

       10001
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `find(C)` function.

It will return the index of any elements in C which are not equal to zero. You should then be able to use the first index returned (from the looks of your plot of C, lets just say this is 4.5 x 10^4).

Then you can calculate the time at which the signal beings to play by dividing 4.5 x 10^4 by the sampling frequency (this is generally 44000 Hz).

Granted this will only work if the first ~4.4 x 10^4 samples are all equal to zero. If this is not the case then you could create a binary array using a conditional on the array C and then call find() on that binary array.

The following example will give you the index where the signal exceeds some threshold value (0.5 in this case).

```
binArray = C > 0.5;
nonZeroIndx = find(binArray);
firstExceedingThreshInC = nonZeroIndx(1);
```